# Sending a message to user when user enters a geofence / area?

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es, aws-lex

I'm making a dialogflow agent that will be integrated with various platforms (Facebook messenger, slack and maybe a few others) that will have the basic functions of a informational chatbot.

The agent will be for a specific store and I'm wondering if it's possible to trigger some sort of welcome message once the user enters the geofence (in this case, the store)?

Thanks for the help. I haven't found any documentation for this on dialogflow specifically or anywhere else so anything will be awesome.

**Note:** I'm am not by any means dead set of dialogflow, if AWS Lex offers something like this and it's better, I will take a look. I'm just a bit more used to dialogflow.

Comment: Dialogflow sessions can only be initiated by the user, everything else would probably get annoying pretty quickly:) You can really only ask your customers to launch your agent or use an entirely different system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be achieved just by using either Lex or Dialogflow. Because at the end of the day, you are using them to integrate with Messenger/Slack/Whatsapp and these apps will (for obvious good reasons) not share the user's location information with the bot. You will need a helper app which takes the user's location permission as well and triggers the bots for you.

Keep in mind that channels like Messenger and Whatsapp have restrictions over sending messages willy-nilly to users. Messenger has a ['24+1' policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy/policy-overview/#24hours_window) Whatsapp also you can only send free form messages in the 24 hour window. But after that you can send chargeable pre-approved "hsm" message templates.

Comment: I figured that to be the case. Thanks for the answer!